# problems with forEach loop

Tags: swift

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let status: String
    let value: [Value]
}
struct Value: Codable {
    let psid: Int
    let name: String
    let valute: String
    let reserve: Double
    let with_codes: Int
    let img: String
}

var good = [Value]()//first array



struct Response1: Codable {
    let status: String
    let value: [Value1]
}
struct Value1: Codable {
    let id: String
    let enabled: Int
    let direct: Int
    let psid1: Int
    let psid2: Int
    let in: Int
    let in_valute: String
    let out: Double
    let out_valute: String
    let in_min: Double
    let in_max: Int
    let reserve: Double
}

var good1 = [Value1]()//second array


good.forEach { goodItem in
  if good1.contains(where: { good1Item -> Bool in
    return good1Item.psid2 == goodItem.psid
  }) {
    print(goodItem)
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I need to output goodItem.name to a table, only the last value is output, although when I check everything in the console, google I found that the return method returns only the last value, how can I fix it?

Comment: What information do you exactly want to extract from your forEach statement ? If you want to extract all items where (good.psid == good1.psid2) you could do :

`var matchingGoods = [Value]();
for i in 0..< good {
    for j in 0..<good1 {
        if good[I].psid2 == good1[j].psid {
             matchingPsid.append(good);
        }
   }
}`

Comment: I think you didn't get for what is forEach intended.

Comment: Yes, you need to extract all the elements where psid = psid1, you need to create a new masive, to use it in the table. For example ; in the good array, 5 elements with psid 1 - 2 -3 -4 -5 and the names q - w - e - r - t and there is another good 1 array in which there is a psid 1 with values ​​from 1 to 3 - 5 from the good array get all the elements with values ​​that are in good1 namely 1 with the name q, 3 with e and 5 with t and use the array just created in the table

Comment: sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
for value in good {
  if good1.filter( {$0.psid2 == value.psid}).count > 0 {
    print(value.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: `filter { }.count > 0` is the same as `contains`, but with worse performance.

Comment: unfortunately does not work, everything is the same as it was, if all the names are displayed in the console, then the output to the cell of the table displays only the last value                                                                for value in good {
            if good1.filter( {$0.psid2 == value.psid}).count > 0 {
                cell2?.PaymentCellText2.text = value.name
            }
        }